# Accessing SSH local tunneling through Docker published port

Tags: ssh, docker, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have the following setup:

```
[OpenSSH server] <---> [Docker container with SSH client] <---> [host machine]
```

My Docker container is a SSH connection manager of sorts. The service running on the OpenSSH server whose port I'm forwarding is a web server.

From inside the container, I can successfully `curl` the tunneled port. However, when I try to publish that same port to my host and try to `curl` from the host, I get

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

---

This is the SSH command I'm using to setup the tunnel:

```
ssh -nNT -L 3000:*:9413 OPENSSH_SERVER_URL
```

I'm running this container using

```
docker run --rm --name test -p 3000:3000 ssh-connection-manager
```

If I login to the container, I can `curl` and get a response:

```
docker exec -it --entrypoint sh test
# curl localhost:3000
Hello!
```

I cannot do the same from the host through the published port:

```
$ curl localhost:3000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

---

What am I missing? I suspect it's a connection option on the SSH client or configuration on my OpenSSH server, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is it the same with `ssh -g …`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `-g` works! I also just discovered that prefixing `0.0.0.0` before the port also works, eg. `ssh -nNT -L 0.0.0.0:3000:*:9413 OPENSSH_SERVER_URL`. If you post an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: I won't post an answer because I know too little (in fact nothing) about Docker (yet) to explain *why* `-g` helps. IMO a good answer should explain this. That said, however, I'm not going to downvote an answer that states the solution without explanation; so if you think this is enough then you post it. In the long term I hope for an explanatory answer though.